# Can't deploy bitnami/rabbitmq Helm Chart on GKE, permission to create role is required

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding

## Introduction :

I am trying to deploy a **RabbitMq** Helm Chart to GKE, with my Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. The command I use to install my chart is:

```
helm upgrade --install rabbitmq --create-namespace --namespace kubi-app-main -f envs/main/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.yaml bitnami/rabbitmq
```

#### envs/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.yaml:

```
auth:
  username: user
  password: password
# The used vhost is default-vhost
extraConfiguration: |-
  default_vhost = default-vhost
  default_permissions.configure = .*
  default_permissions.read = .*
  default_permissions.write = .*
```

The Gitlab job first connect to GKE cluster with gcloud:

```
echo "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY" > key.json
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json
gcloud config set project project-kubi-app
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-1 --zone europe-west9-a --project project-kubi-app
```

## The Issue:

But the helm upgrade fails:

> Error: roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "kubiapp-cluster-sa@project-kubi-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com" cannot create resource "roles" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" in the namespace "kubi-app-main": requires one of ["container.roles.create"] permission(s).

- Checking the roles of the user (service account) on the project

> gcloud projects get-iam-policy project-kubi-app  --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:kubiapp-cluster-sa@project-kubi-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

This will return `ROLE roles/editor`, meaning that my service account has an editor role on the project.

---

From what I understand, the service account **kubiapp-cluster-sa@project-kubi-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com** has the editor role on the project **project-kubi-app**. 
**BUT** the service account that I am using can't create a role in the namespace **kubi-app-main**.
I don't understand the use of this role, but it's origin is from the RabbitMq Helm Chart.

From the RabbitMq Helm Chart:

```
...
# Source: rabbitmq/templates/rolebinding.yaml
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-endpoint-reader
  namespace: "kubi-app-main"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
    helm.sh/chart: rabbitmq-10.1.8
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: rabbitmq
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: rabbitmq
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: rabbitmq-endpoint-reader
...
---
```

---

## EDIT:

I have changed my service account role to Owner and now it works, but I would like to know the role required to create other roles.

Comment: In GCP, there are 3 basic role types: [basic, predefined and custom](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#role_types).

The one you used is "Owner", it belongs to "basic".

Based on your question above, I think this is what you're looking for: [Custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#custom_roles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roles/editor` allows you to create/update/delete resources for most/many services, but does not include the permission to perform any of those operations on roles in general.  `roles/owner`, on the other hand, does as it essentially makes you an admin of (almost every) resource.

For GKE, the usual role required to create/modify/update roles within the cluster is `roles/container.clusterAdmin`.  Check out [GKE roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles).

Comment: It's also named `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin` in GKE.